# Update only one column in GCP datastore table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, datastore

I want to update only one column in GCP Datastore table.
For Example : Table has columns id, name, descriptions, price, data.

I receive data to update only descriptions. I want to update only descriptions column without reading other data.(want to avoid read before write)

It is possible to update only column of datastore without reading data from datastore.
If not what other database in GCp allow to do it?

Comment: There is no column on Datastore, it's a document database. Are you sure it's the correct product name? If so, you can't, it's an update of all the documents: you change the JSON structure from.

Comment: As mentioned in above comment, Cloud Datastore  is a document database which stores entities and each entity has a set of properties.you can check this document [1](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#updating_an_entity) & [2](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/editing_entity_console#edit_a_property) to update an entity

Comment: Thanks. I read documents and do POC. It can not update only one column as it is entity. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Datastore is a document database which stores entities, and there are no fixed columns or schema. Instead, each entity can have a different set of properties, which are similar to columns in a traditional relational database.check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview) for more information

You cannot update specific properties of an entity.As this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) says you have to update the entire entity.To update a specific property of an entity, you would need to retrieve the entire entity, modify the desired property, and then write the entire entity back to the database.